# Python: Fill space between two lines drawn on a Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have drawn two lines on a Basemap created in python. Each line is created with two points (start and end points). Both lines originate from the same point.

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=119.46,llcrnrlat=21.62,urcrnrlon=121.406,urcrnrlat=23.43, resolution = 'i', epsg=3825)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.plot([x, x1], [y, y1])
m.plot([x, x2], [y, y2])
```

Resulting in a plot like this:
[image]

I would like to shade in the area between these two lines (the larger slice on the lower left). I know it involves some use of fill_between() and/or fill_betweenx(), but I can't figure it out.

More generally:
I have two lines originating from a center point. The lines represent the sweep range of a radar. I want to fill in the area NOT included in this sweep range. This needs to work for any two lines (any sweep range). I can also pull out the beginning and ending azimuths in degrees of the sweep, if we need that.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a wedge patch object and using the azimuths of the radar sweeps.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=119.46,llcrnrlat=21.62,urcrnrlon=121.406,urcrnrlat=23.43, resolution = 'i', epsg=3825)
m.drawcoastlines()
wedge = Wedge((x,y), 200000, az2, az1, edgecolor="none", color = 'grey', alpha = 0.2)
ax.add_patch(wedge)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Wish it help!

```
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=119.46,llcrnrlat=21.62,urcrnrlon=121.406,urcrnrlat=23.43, resolution = 'i', epsg=3825)
m.drawcoastlines()

x,y = (119.46 + 121.406)/2.0,(21.62+23.43)/2.0
x1,y1 = 120.0,24.0
x2,y2 = 124.0,22.0
lons = np.array([x1,x, x2, x2,x1])
lats = np.array([y1, y, y2, y1,y1])
x, y = m( lons, lats )
xy = zip(x,y)
poly = Polygon( xy, facecolor='b', alpha=0.75 ,edgecolor = 'r', zorder =15,linewidth = 2)
plt.gca().add_patch(poly)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(21.0,24.0,0.5),labels=[1,0,0,1],size=12,linewidth=0,color= '#FFFFFF')
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(119.8,121.5,0.5),labels=[1,0,0,1],size=12,linewidth=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I misspoke in the original question... turns out I need the LARGER slice (lower left) to be filled in...

Also, would his wok for any arbitrary line end points? The lines will always originate from the center, but could end at any point along the border of the map.

Comment: To clarify: I have two lines originating from a center point. The lines represent the sweep range of a radar. I want to fill in the area NOT included in this sweep range. This needs to work for any two lines (any sweep range). I can also pull out the beginning and ending azimuths in degrees of the sweep, if we need that.